# Consuming a SOAP Web Service with the lowest overhead

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, dataset

I'm implementing a SOAP Webservice for sending thousands of emails and storing thousands of XML response records in a local database. (c#.net, visual studio 2012)

I would like to make my service consumer as fast and lightweight as possible.
I need to know some of the considerations. I always have a feeling that my code should run faster than it is.

E.g.

1. I've read that using datasets increase overhead. So should I use lists of objects instead?
2. Does using ORM introduce slowness into my code?
3. Is a console application faster than a winform? Because the user needs no GUI to deal with. There are simply some parameters sent to the app that invoke some methods.

What are the most efficient ways to deal with a SOAP Web Service?

Comment: It's a little unclear to me which part you are trying to optimize. You say you would like to make the service 'consumer' as fast as possible. Is the consumer the one sending the emails and storing the records in the database? Can you go into more detail about this? If the service is doing all the work you just have to fire it off asynchronously on the client-side. Do you need results back before the client can continue?

Comment: Eric Lippert just blogged some great advice when considering improving performance of an application.  http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=performance-rant

Answer (score 2):

Make it work, then worry about making it fast.  If you try to guess where the bottle necks will be, you will probably guess wrong.  The best way to optimize something is to measure real code before and after.

Datasets and ORM and win form apps, and console apps can all run plenty fast.  Use the technologies that suit you, then tune the speed if you actually need it.

Finally if you do have a performance problem, changing your choice of algorithms to better suit your problem will likely yield much greater performance impact than changing any of the technologies you mentioned.

Comment: I have made it work before and this one will also be the same. Because it's very similar to what I have done in the past. So that won't be a burden. I just needed some wise words regarding the speed of my product.

Comment: @Pedram: In my opinion, the only chance to really increase the performace is to use REST instead of SOAP

Comment: Alas the API does not have a REST version. It's for a company and we just have to consume it.

Comment: @Pedram perfect, then you already have something to measure so grab a profiler and go measure your existing app.  That way you can find specific problems and solutions rather than speculate on generalities.

Comment: @Rafa, how will REST make a web service faster?  At the end of the day you are still parsing a bunch of text that came in over the wire.

Comment: @Scott6: In my opinion, SOAP has much more overhead. In SOAP you are parsing a very big bunch of text, in REST only the bunch of text that you really want to send. This is my experience with this kind of web services under MS technologies. It may be faster with Java, I don't know.

Comment: @Rafa, a REST format is likely to be less verbose and therefore faster to parse than SOAP, but I suspect very few apps spend much of their time in parsing the message.  Data access, or calculations to service the request are likely to take much much more time than parsing the message.  Again a case where you really need a measurement to prove that the SOAP format is a performance problem before attempting to optimize it.

Answer (score 2):

Considering my personal experience with soap, in this scenario I would say your main concern should be on how you retrieve this information from your database (procedures, views, triggers, indexes and etc).

The difference between console, winform and webapp isn't that relevant.

After the app is done you should make a huge stress test on it to be able to see where lies your performance problem, if it exists.

Comment: the database interaction is only INSERT queries. But I'm looking an optimized way to insert them. In the past I gathered the whole web service response into a dataset and looped through it to insert the records. is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: @Pedram, now you are looking at this the right way.  Look for specific problems and solutions to those specific problems.  Of course you should still measure to see if the time spent on inserts is significant to you application before changing it.

Comment: @Pedram, you should consider looking at SqlBulkCopy as far as I remember you can BulkCopy an entire DataSet into a datatable, it should be faster than iterating on a dataset to insert one by one.